# Console Errors getting css files

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having some errors linking to my css files from my html. I am getting the following errors.

```
    GET http://localhost:3000/app/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.css 
        habits:30 
    GET http://localhost:3000/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss 
        habits:34 
    GET http://localhost:3000/assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js 
        habits:52 
    GET http://localhost:3000/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js 
        habits.self-f894a4f031f58f24694feda9c89f464976d99c2eda34ee3f03c956dc29757a67.js?body=1:8 
Uncaught ReferenceError: Handsontable is not defined
```

I know that the first four is from an error referencing the css file from my html file, but what is the last error for? And how would I fix it?

Comment: Handsontable is either an object or method in the javascript/script with is not defined.

Comment: Thanks I am working with the rails on the backend, so would I include a file/the files (I guess I don't really know which file to include as well) in the app/assets/javascript directory?

Comment: inculde 'it', what is it?

Answer (score 1):

The Uncaught ReferenceError sometimes means you don't have your javascript files in the correct order. For instance, if a script relies on jQuery but gets loaded first, you'll get this error.

Without viewing the entire code it's impossible to say exactly where the problem lies, but I've found that linking jQuery first, then other scripts, generally fixes the error.

One way to avoid this error is to put a conditional script in the header like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
   document.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"[jquery CDN of your choice]\"></" + "script>");
}
</script>
```